# Only counting from one drop down check list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a validation method that will count from all of the check lists on the page, but I only want to count from one of the two drop down lists.

Checklist:

```
$("#s1").dropdownchecklist({ emptyText: "Please select at least one...", width: 300, maxDropHeight: 200 });
```

Method:

```
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("categoryCount", function(value, element) {
            var count = 0;
            var n = $("input:checked").length;
            alert("category Count was called: " + n);                       
            return !(count>3);
        }, "Choose less than 3.");
```

I know the problem lies in the third line of the method,

```
$("input:checked").length;
```

but how do I make it do what I want?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: It might help to explain where `dropdownchecklist(` is derived from as that seems to not be indicated and is not a "standard" thing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you are looking for. I was just recently thrown into this project and asked to do some validation without any javascript knowledge. As far as I can tell it is something made available through jquery. I hope that might help? Sorry if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the following code to find the checked items: `var n = $("input:checked").length;`.  If you want to limit your search to specific items, there are several ways to go about this.

One ways would be to enclose the items within `<div class='enclosure'>` tags.  Then change
`var n = $("input:checked").length;`
 to
`var n = $('.enclosure').find('input:checked').length;`

Answer (score 0):

im new to JS and SO i would've preferred to put this in a comment but i don't have  the rep to do that yet so i will post it here. 
i have noticed that other people on this site use

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').length
```

instead of

```
     var n = $("input:checked").length;
```

This might be the cause of the error.